# How to slash number at the picture below?

Tags: equations, rules

How to slash numbers how it done at the picture?

[image]

It's the part of equation:

```
 \usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,mathtools}
 ...
 \[
      \begin{Bmatrix}
           (000)\\
           (100)
      \end{Bmatrix}
 \]
```

I suppose that need to use TikZ, but don't sure that it is a good way for solve this problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`tikz` is not necessary, just use a vertical rule with some spacing:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \begin{Bmatrix}
    ( 0\mkern-5mu\smash{\vrule height 0.8em depth 1.5em}\mkern5mu00)\\
    (100)
  \end{Bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: there's a simpler way to enter this package list.  (yes, i know this is what is in the original example.)  `amssymb` loads `amsfonts`, so `amsfonts` isn't needed.  and `mathtools` loads `amsmath`, so another simplification is possible.  (although it's sometimes a useful reminder to explicitly show that `amsmath` is being used.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Perfectly correct - I have just removed `amsfonts` as you suggest, as you say the `mathtools+amsmath` redunancy can be a useful reminder.